# Excel convert into encoded string and then re-write in excel

Tags: java, excel

I am working on a poc where i need to convert any text file or excel file into encoded string and send as a rest api string body

Now converting plane text file into string and then re construct file without any problem

Now i am unable to  re construct encoded string of excel to original excel file.

Getting corrupt file when converting it to excel file..

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedExcelString);
        BufferedOutputStream w = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("path"));
        w.write(decoded.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same scenario, I am not much familiar with excel creation scenario and char format type, but in normal case It will work ..

```
 byte[] bytes = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encodeData);
  try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
        fos.write(bytes);
    }
```

Also please avoid encoded string for binary files, for normal text file it is ok to wrap  with in enocded string but in case of large binary file it will take much process time. Instead of string use array of bytes.